# Scientific notation in Python - extra digits

Tags: python, floating-point, scientific-notation

I have the following very small floating number in Python:

```
fnum = 0.00012345689000007
```

When I try to convert to a scientific notation, I am not sure where the extra digits after 7 (the last digit) are coming from:

```
print("%.40e"%fnum)
```

This is the result: '1.2345689000007001204055334664388965393300e-04'

I would be happy if someone could explain.

Comment: The answer is, "don't do that".  A double-precision floating point value only has 15 or 16 digits of precision.  Anything after that point is garbage.

Comment: @Danny 0.00012345689000007 is typically saved as a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  That 64-bit type can exactly encode about 2^64 different values as  [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).  As 0.00012345689000007 is **not** one of them, the nearest  one is 0x102e869c2b1457*2^(-13-52) or exactly 0.00012345689000007001204055334664388965393300168216228485107421875.

Comment: @TimRoberts "...only has 15 or 16 digits of precision. Anything after that point is garbage" --> Not quite.  It takes up to 17 significant decimal digits to correctly round-trip _float_ to text, back to the same _float_.  Digits past that have increasing limited usefulness